# Group representation in displacive phase transition

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I have a problem in understanding why something is a group representation from a given equation.

Let $\phi_i$ be the set of $n$ basis vectors of a vector space $S'$. Operating with $g$ on any element of $S'$ result in another vector in $S'$. So by acting with $g$ on a basis vector can be obviously written as a linear combination of basis vectors
$$g \phi_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \phi_j D_{ji}(g),$$
where $D_{ji}$ is a matrix that depends on $g$. The author of the [paper](https://iso.byu.edu/iso/isotheory.pdf) now says that from the equation above it follows that $D(g_i)D(g_j)=D(g_i g_j)$. But how does he get to this conclusion? I have tried to operate on the left hand side of the equation with two different $g$ operators getting two $D$ matrices on the right hand side inside two summations but then I am stuck again.

For the context: I am simulating phase transistions in crystals using DFT and now I am trying to understand the underlying theory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get $D(g_1 g_2) = D(g_2) D(g_1),$ i.e. the opposite order:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \phi_k D_{ki}(g_1 g_2)
= (g_1 g_2) \phi_i 
= g_1 (g_2 \phi_i)
= \sum_{j=1}^n (g_2 \phi_j) D_{ji}(g_1)
\\
= \sum_{j=1}^n ( \sum_{k=1}^n \phi_k D_{kj}(g_2) ) D_{ji}(g_1)
\\
= \sum_{k=1}^n \phi_k ( \sum_{j=1}^n D_{kj}(g_2) D_{ji}(g_1) )
$$
Thus,
$$
D_{ki}(g_1 g_2) = \sum_{j=1}^n D_{kj}(g_2) D_{ji}(g_1),
$$
i.e. $D(g_1 g_2) = D(g_2) D(g_1)$ as matrices.

Comment: Thanks! What did you do in the last step?

Comment: Here I just swap order of summations:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n (\sum_{k=1}^n \phi_k D_{kj}(g_2) D_{ji}(g_1)
\\
= \sum_{k=1}^n \phi_k \left( \sum_{j=1}^n D_{kj}(g_2) D_{ji}(g_1) \right)$$

Comment: No I meant the very last step, but I already understood it - thank you! But I also do not understand why in the paper he comes to the opposite order!

Comment: I've tried to look through my calculations, but find no error. I think that there's a mistake in the paper. If one instead takes $g \phi_i = \sum_{j=1}^n D_{ij}(g) \phi_j,$ then the result would be $D(g_1 g_2) = D(g_1) D(g_2),$ I think.

Comment: But only in this case it is a homomorphism and thus a group representation right?

Comment: According to the precise definitions, yes, but in practice it doesn't matter that much.